# Пропадают dropdown пункты меню bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Друзья, столкнулся с проблемой в joomla.
Сделал шаблон на bootstrap 3, все работало, как часы.
Поставил компонент на bootstrap 2 и почти доточил до 3-ки, но есть проблема: на странице с компонентом пропадают открытые пункты в dropdown menu, то есть 1 раз открывается меню, а потом пункт просто исчезает.
Где может быть проблема?
Спасибо!

Comment: @zrenie, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

@zrenie, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ASyr2nE1D8

проблема в js бутстрапа 3. в видео показано как поправить
если короче, то в
bootstrap.js (или в сжатой версии) в функции `clearMenus(e)`
стереть `hide` в строчке

`$parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))`

то есть должно получиться:

`$parent.trigger(e = $.Event('bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))`